# Display selected html tag only that is stores in js variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

above code is responseText from ajax call.

Now I am using below syntax.

```
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

And this displays all html tags from response.

What i want is  to display only div2 tag element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank Arun Sir for edit

Comment: please post your ajax request page

Comment: Thank Man .. MrCode  it worked flawless.

Comment: Can i similarly add/modify css code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a jQuery object out of the responseText and use find:

```
$('#Result').empty().append($(xmlhttp.responseText).find('#div2'));
```

Comment: What is the use of find there $(xmlhttp.responseText).find('#div2'), *id should be unique*

Comment: @Bala indeed IDs should be unique, but what does that have to do with the question/answer?

Comment: @MrCode you can give simply like that $('#Result').html($('#div2'));

Answer (score 0):

You need to only specify the required parts in ajax request page, otherwise `xmlhttp.responseText` will return all the HTML and print statements given in the request page.

for example, in the case of JSP

```
<html>
<%
out.print("something")
%>
</html>
```

ajax:

`xmlhttp.responseText` will return both html tag and the print text 'something'

actual result will be: `<html>something</html>`

so you need to remove unwanted html/printing statements from your request page.

By doing this, you dont need to search the response text for a particular markup uisng JavaScript/Jquery.